# Service Availability monitoring on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to display Service Availability (%) for metric i have on AWS, I am able to get graphs, but can't get availability for period selected.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. Exactly what metric are you using to view availability? You can get min/max/average/sum for a metric [using the command line](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SingleMetricPerInstance.html), and there's probably a way to download the raw data to work it out yourself. It might be simpler to use a site uptime type service if it suits what you need.

Comment: @Tim metrics from Cloudwatch itself, like stats from load balancer

Comment: EXACTLY what metric? I don't think there's on the gives availability is there? You can get the general idea based on load / throughput / requests.

Comment: Metric that i have in cloudwatch